# Export value from external highcharts website

Tags: php, highcharts, jscript

i would like to import the hourly rain value (Niederschlag) from a highcharts weather station ([www.highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com)) as a plain number for my home automation.
So I can run a script in my homeautomation to get this value every hour.

Best thing would be a HTML line with which I could use the CURL command in my homeautomation script.

This is the website: https://klima.rgeo.de/stations/de_14_gaiberg/

Thx guys!

Greetz duffy6

Comment: Hi @duffy6, How this question is related with Highcharts? However, you can get the value by running this JS code: `document.getElementsByClassName('value')[0].innerText`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am a newbie in JS (and programming at all). Is it possible you guys give me a little more code (especially for this task)? Thx!